# Remove all grouped rows / columns in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet that does dynamic grouping with a script. I am looking for a function that gets rid of all those [Groups](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/group) in the sheet again.

Similar to [`expandAllColumnGroups`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#expandallcolumngroups), I would like to have a function called `removeAllColumnGroups` - but it seems there is no such function available.

My current approach is very slow and cumbersome. I did quite some research but could not even find a way to get all the `columnGroups` or at least the start-column-IDs in a sheet, so I iterate over every column and literally **try** to remove the group if there is one, as there is no way to tell if a group exits. Unfortunately for about 90 columns this takes ages (minutes, really)...

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();

  //remove all column-groups
  var group = null;
  var maxCol = sh.getMaxColumns();
  for(var c = 1; c <= maxCol; c++) {
    try {
      group = sh.getColumnGroup(c, 1); // Try to get group
      group.remove(); // Remove the group
    } catch (e) {
      //Logger.log("No Group at ColIndex "+c);
    }
  }
```

Any ideas would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the Sheets API - you can easily access available groups and remove them.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Could you please be a little more specific? I'm a bit lost in the API docs... Is this the right location to investigate further? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/

Comment: @i that's a good solution for sheets without formulas, unless other sheets user it for formulas as they will get reference errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on my comment re: use of the Google Sheets REST API to access and modify row/column groupings:

Row/Column groups are metadata associated with a `Sheet` resource, and as such can be obtained for all sheets in a workbook with a single HTTP request to [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get), with the appropriate `fields` specification:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID}?fields=sheets(columnGroups%2Cproperties(sheetId%2Ctitle)%2CrowGroups)&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

[Demo link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.get?spreadsheetId=%7BYOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID%7D&fields=sheets(columnGroups%252Cproperties(sheetId%252Ctitle)%252CrowGroups))

The above request returns an object with a `sheets` property, which is an array of objects (1 per sheet in the spreadsheet) having 3 properties: `rowGroups`, `columnGroups`, and `properties`. The group properties are arrays of [`DimensionGroup`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#DimensionGroup) objects, while the `properties` object contains the sheet's gridId/sheetId, which you need for identifying the sheet in various API requests, and its name (which may be useful for your own script logic).

To delete every row/column group, you need to issue as many [`DeleteDimensionGroupRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#DeleteDimensionGroupRequest)s to do so as the maximum `depth` returned in your query's groups. If you do not specify the indices of the [`DimensionRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DimensionRange) in your request, this is interpreted as the whole range of the spreadsheet (all rows / all columns, depending on direction).

An example request (requires OAuth authentication, not just API key):

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{YOUR SPREADSHEET ID}:batchUpdate?fields=replies%2FdeleteDimensionGroup

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "deleteDimensionGroup": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": "{SHEET 1 ID}",
          "dimension": "COLUMNS"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "deleteDimensionGroup": {
        "range": {
          "sheetId": "{SHEET 2 ID}"
          "dimension": "COLUMNS",
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

[Demo link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate?spreadsheetId=YOUR+SPREADSHEET+ID&fields=replies%252FdeleteDimensionGroup&_h=4&resource=%257B%250A++%2522requests%2522%253A+%250A++%255B%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522deleteDimensionGroup%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522range%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522sheetId%2522%253A+%2522%257BSHEET+1+ID%257D%2522%252C%250A++++++++++%2522dimension%2522%253A+%2522COLUMNS%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%252C%250A++++%257B%250A++++++%2522deleteDimensionGroup%2522%253A+%250A++++++%257B%250A++++++++%2522range%2522%253A+%250A++++++++%257B%250A++++++++++%2522dimension%2522%253A+%2522COLUMNS%2522%252C%250A++++++++++%2522sheetId%2522%253A+%2522%257BSHEET+2+ID%257D%2522%250A++++++++%257D%250A++++++%257D%250A++++%257D%250A++%255D%250A%257D&)

Each delete request has a [reply response](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/response#deletedimensiongroupresponse), and that response will be very similar to the initial response you got for the row/column groups from the initial query. If you knew the gridIds beforehand, you could forgo the initial query and use a while loop to keep sending delete requests while the response contains a dimension group.

---

To use these methods with Google Apps Script, you can either use `UrlFetchApp` with raw URL resources, or take advantage of the available ["advanced service"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) client library [`Sheets`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) (which must first be enabled). Both methods require you to enable use of the Sheets API from your script's [Google Cloud Platform project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) page.

An example using the enabled client library `Sheets`:

```
function removeAllGroups() {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
        wbId = wb.getId();
  const initial = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(wbId, {
    fields: "sheets(columnGroups,properties(sheetId,title),rowGroups)"
  });

  // Determine the maximum depth of row & column groups on each sheet in the workbook.
  const maxDepths = {row: {}, col: {}};
  initial.sheets.forEach(function (s) {
    // if (s.properties.title ... (could write logic to do this only for certain sheets)
    var sId = s.properties.sheetId;
    if (s.columnGroups && s.columnGroups.length)
      maxDepths.col[sId] = s.columnGroups.reduce(dgMaxDepth_, 0);
    if (s.rowGroups && s.rowGroups.length)
      maxDepths.row[sId] = s.rowGroups.reduce(dgMaxDepth_, 0);
  });

  // Add all delete requests to an array
  const rqs = [];
  for (var rqType in maxDepths) {
    for (var sheetId in maxDepths[rqType]) {
      addDeleteDGRequests_(rqs, rqType, sheetId, maxDepths[rqType][sheetId]);
    }
  }

  // Send all requests.
  if (rqs.length) {
    const replies = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: rqs}, wbId);
    console.log({message: "Batch response", response: replies});
  }
}

// Callback for Array#reduce
function dgMaxDepth_(val, dg, i, allDGs) {
  return Math.max(val, dg.depth);
}

function addDeleteDGRequests_(requests, rqType, sheetId, num) {
  const dim = rqType === "col" ? "COLUMNS" : "ROWS";
  while (num > 0) {
    var rq = {
      deleteDimensionGroup: {
        range: { sheetId: sheetId,
                 dimension: dim }
      }
    };
    requests.push(rq);
    --num;
  }
}
```

Resources:

- [Google APIs Explorer - Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/sheets/v4/)
- [Google Sheets REST API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference)
- [Enable Advanced Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation! Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution.

```js
function removeAllGroupsFromSheet() {
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let lastRow = sheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  
  for (let row = 1; row < lastRow; row++) {
    let depth = sheet.getRowGroupDepth(row);
    if (depth < 1) continue;
    sheet.getRowGroup(row, depth).remove();
  }
}
```